# The usage of the word 'y'

Tags: pronoms-personnels

J'ai un ordinateur et des jeux mais c'est mon petit frère qui y joue toujours.

I don't understand the way the word 'y'is used in this sentence.

Comment: How familiar are you with the pronoun *y* in general ? Does it solve your question to know that "*to play a game*" is "*jouer **à** un jeu*" in French ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Y in this case is replacing the use of "un ordinateur", effectively making the statement less verbose.

For example, you could phrase it as:

"J'ai un ordinateur et des jeux mais c'est mon petit frère q**ui joue toujours a l'ordinateur**"

and it would make just as much sense.

It would be the same in English as contracting the sentence:

"I have a computer and some games, but my little brother **plays on the computer all the time**"

To:

"I have a computer and some games, but my little brother plays **on it** all the time."

Comment: Actually, "y" stands in for the whole "un ordinateur et des jeux", IMHO. But small detail :-)

Comment: Couldn't you say- J'ai un ordinateur et des jeux mais c'est mon petit frère qui le joue toujours.

Comment: Nope - that would now not be correct, because the verb "jouer" is not transitive. We say "jouer a qqchose", not "jouer qqchose" in this case, although we do say "jouer <un personnage de théâtre>" and "jouer une symphonie", "jouer une mélodie", "jouer un morceau".